# Nesting double condition formulas

Tags: calculated-column

I need to nest several formulas just like this one: =IF(Service="ACB",(IF([Fac/Fellow]="Faculty","002701284","")),"").

So first condition is:
=IF(Service="ACB",(IF([Fac/Fellow]="Faculty","002701284","")),"")

Second condition is 
=If(Service="Surgery",(IF([Fac/Fellow]="Fellow",002701294,"")),"")

Any ideas? I've nested 8 single condition formulas successfully but I can't figure out these double condition formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have only one calculated column where all the conditions, you must put next condition in statement else previous conditions.

For you conditions example:

IF(Service="ACB",(IF([Fac/Fellow]="Faculty","002701284","")),(IF(Service="Surgery",(IF([Fac/Fellow]="Fellow","002701294","")),"")))

Comment: Thank you! I think I was messing up my brackets when I was trying.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: If I've helped, you can always vote for my answer :)